# Do you have to fly to an airport with an instructor before you can solo there?

Tags: faa-regulations, general-aviation, flight-training, solo-flight

I am currently doing my flight training and my CFI said that before I can fly solo to another airport he needs to fly with me there first. Is this true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer:

Your instructor is correct, if the airport is less than 50 miles away, or is in class B airspace. If it's more than 50 miles away then you don't need to fly there together first.

---

Long answer:

It depends on the solo endorsement that your instructor plans to give you. There are two sections of regulations that apply to student solos to other airports, in [14 CFR 61.93](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61#61.93). Your instructor is probably talking about the requirements in 61.93(b) that apply to solo flights of less than 25 or 50 miles.

61.93(b)(1) says (emphasis mine):

> (1) Solo flights may be made to another airport that is **within 25
> nautical miles** from the airport where the student pilot normally
> receives training, provided -
>
> (i) An authorized instructor **has given the student pilot flight
> training at the other airport**, and that training includes flight in
> both directions over the route, entering and exiting the traffic
> pattern, and takeoffs and landings at the other airport;

61.93(b)(2) says (emphasis mine):

> (2) Repeated specific solo cross-country flights may be made to
> another airport that is **within 50 nautical miles** of the airport from
> which the flight originated, provided -
>
> (i) The authorized instructor **has given the student flight training in
> both directions over the route**, including entering and exiting the
> traffic patterns, takeoffs, and landings at the airports to be used;

But, for a solo flight that takes you *50 miles or more* away from your home base only the general requirements in 61.93(a) and (c) apply. They don't state that the instructor has to give you flight training at the destination. That would apply to your 150 mile solo cross country, for example.

Additionally, [61.95(b)(1)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61#61.95) requires training at an airport in class B before a student can fly there (emphasis mine):

> (b) A student pilot may not operate an aircraft on a solo flight to,
> from, or at an airport located within Class B airspace pursuant to §
> 91.131(b) of this chapter unless:
>
> (1) The student pilot has received both ground and flight training
> from an instructor authorized to provide training to operate at that
> airport, and **the flight and ground training has been received at the
> specific airport for which the solo flight is authorized**;

Having said all that, 61.93(a)(2)(iv) allows an instructor to put any conditions they like on a cross country endorsement:

> Comply with any limitations included in the authorized instructor's
> endorsement that are required by paragraph (c) of this section.

It's possible that your instructor wants to limit you to airports that you've already flown to together, either for his own comfort level or for owner/insurance reasons.

I suggest you ask your instructor to talk through the various solo endorsements with you and explain which ones he'll provide and when.

Comment: I had one CFI that limited solo XC to airports I’d previously visited with him, and another CFI (same school!) who believed the point of a solo XC was going places I *hadn’t* been to before. Both positions are understandable, and the FARs don’t rule out either.